# state is undefined in useLocation even after assigning the value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**state prop is undefined in useLocation hook in react , can access pathname but state is showing undefined**

```
{users.map((item) => {

                    return (<tr key={item.id}><td>{item.name} </td>
                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                        <td>{item.account}</td>
                        <td>{item.amount}</td>
                        <td><Link to={{pathname: `/users/${item.name}`, state: {
                                name: item.name,
                                account:item.account
                            }
                        }}> Transfer </Link></td>
                    </tr>)


                })}
```

**I'm passing, pathname, and state but can only access pathname , the state is undefined even after hardcoding the values**
**on the directed component **

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams , useLocation} from 'react-router'
const Demo = ()=> {
const {transfer} = useParams()
const location = useLocation()
console.log(transfer ,location.state)
return (
    <div>
        hello {transfer}{location.state}
    </div>
)
```

}

**output : transfer , undefined**

**why location.state is undefined**

Comment: Are you wrapping the rendered item in the BrowserRouter?

Comment: yes , every thing is wraaped

Comment: To be more explicit, be sure you aren't using `<HashRouter>` which doesn't support location state.

Comment: no im useing browserrouter , route , Link all conventional tags from react -router-dom